# Parsing formatted Date String in another TimeZone to date object not working

Tags: java, timezone

I am trying to convert a formatted date String to Date object. Date String is formatted to some other timezone.

When I do `sdf.parse(String)` it returns me my System date object.

Code is as below,

```
static Date convertGMTTime(String timeZone, long longDate){
    Date convertedTime = null;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    try{
        Date date = new Date(longDate);
        System.out.println("timezone: "+timeZone +", timestamp: "+date);
        Locale locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
        TimeZone destTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone);// TimeZone.getDefault();
        System.out.println("Source timezone: "+destTimeZone);
/*          DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
                    DateFormat.DEFAULT,
                    DateFormat.DEFAULT,
                    locale);
        formatter.setTimeZone(destTimeZone);*/
        sdf.setTimeZone(destTimeZone);
        String convertedDateStr = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println("convertedDateStr: "+convertedDateStr);
        convertedTime = sdf.parse(convertedDateStr);
        System.out.println("convertedTime: "+convertedTime + "sdf: "+sdf.getTimeZone());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return convertedTime;
}
```

I would appreciate if anyone could help and point out where I am going wrong. 
Thanks in advance.

Output:

> timezone: Atlantic/Cape_Verde, timestamp: Tue Jun 26 17:38:11 IST 2012
>    Source timezone:     sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Atlantic/Cape_Verde",offset=-3600000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=6,lastRule=null]
>
> convertedDateStr: 2012-06-26 11:08:11
>
> convertedTime: Tue Jun 26 17:38:11 IST 2012
>   sdf:sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Atlantic/Cape_Verde",offset=-3600000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=6,lastRule=null]

---

Some more details to share,  When I use another sdf object(without setting timezone for it), It do return me correct time and date but still timezone is picked from System clock

Code

```
static Date convertGMTTime(String timeZone, long longDate){
    Date convertedTime = null;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat sdfParse = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    try{
        Date date = new Date(longDate);
        TimeZone destTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone);// TimeZone.getDefault();
        System.out.println("Source timezone: "+destTimeZone);
        sdf.setTimeZone(destTimeZone);
        String convertedDateStr = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println("convertedDateStr: "+convertedDateStr );
        convertedTime = sdfParse.parse(convertedDateStr,new ParsePosition(0));
        System.out.println("convertedTime: "+convertedTime + "sdf: "+sdf.getTimeZone());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return convertedTime;
}
```

Output

```
Source timezone: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Atlantic/Cape_Verde",offset=-3600000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=6,lastRule=null]

convertedDateStr: 2012-06-26 12:24:56

convertedTime: Tue Jun 26 12:24:56 IST 2012 

sdf: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Atlantic/Cape_Verde",offset=-3600000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=6,lastRule=null]
```

I understand that when I do not assign timezone to sdf it takes System time zone, but why doesn't it show time in System time zone? I shows it in timezone as it was in String but Timezone is different.

Ans when I set timezone it returns date object as per my system time irrespective of the fact that sdf has some other time zone set.

Can anyone please explain the functional behavior for sdf.parse and sdf.format.

For me sdf.setTimeZone() does have its impact when we use format and it is nullified when we use sdf.parse(). I find it quite strange.

Appreciate help in this regard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already have a Date (or the number of milliseconds of the Date), so there is nothing to convert. A Date doesn't have any time zone. It's a universal instant in time. The time zone is relevant only when you **display** this date, because the date 65647678000 could be 12:38 in some time zone, but 10:38 in some other time zone. It's also relevant when you **parse** the String representation of a Date, because 10:38 is 65647678000 in some time zone, but is 65657678000 in some other.

While you don't display a Date object, or parse a String to a Date, you don't need to care about time zones. And to choose the time zone used when displaying/parsing it, set the time zone of the `DateFormat`, and then use `DateFormat.format()`/`DateFormat.parse()` to format/parse the date.

When you use `Date.toString()` to display a date, it will always use your current time zone.

I find it easier to understand what I mean by not thinking of a Date as a day, a month, a year, an hour, etc., but as a moment: "when Kennedy was shot". "When Kennedy was shot" is the same moment for everyone. But if you represent the moment "when Kennedy was shot" in Dallas time zone, it's not the same result as the result you get when you represent this same moment in Paris time zone.

Comment: Thanks for replying and sharing valuable info. I need my method to return Date object as it will be in given timezone. While using parse(String) method I get Date object in my current timezone.  My application requires a user to set his timezone in his profile and I want a generic method where in I can return a Date object as it will be in that time zone.

Comment: I do understand the fact that date is an instant of time in all time zones and its just how we display/view that instant of time varies according to timezones. Now, my concern is that, Can I preserver a Date object in a particular time zone? I have a String with time instant preserved for a particular time zone. I want to parse it and get Date object with time instant details as per given timezone. Not sure if it possible, for me it always gives me date object in my System time zone. Any help/work around to achieve is highly appreciated.

Comment: As I said: a Date object doesn't have a timezone. You think it has one because the toString() method returns a String containing your time zone. But this time zone is the default time zone of the JVM. It's not in the Date object. You could use a Calendar instance, which has a TimeZone. Or you could get the TimeZone in the user's preferences each time you need to parse/display a Date object for this user.

Comment: Parsing a String to get Date object doesnot work for me as it returns me object with time in JVM time zone(as you said above). I require a Date object with time in timezones(i got your point that date does not have time zones) to compare one time instances in different time zones(e.g 10:30 in IST and 10:30 in CST). I initially thought of doing it using Date object. Please tell me if that is possible.

Comment: You could use a Calendar instance, which has a TimeZone. Or you could get the TimeZone in the user's preferences each time you need to parse/display a Date object for this user.