# Convert timestamp coming from a known time zone to the system's time zone

Tags: java, timezone

```
dateFormatterLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
dateFormatterLocal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New York"));
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    timeStampArrayList.add(dateFormatterLocal.parse(list[i]));
}
```

My current code is not converting the timestamp that is known to be in UTC time zone to my time zone.

I would also like to know how to get the system's current time zone instead of having to tell it "America/New York" if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question (but what's new ;)).  If you don't want to have to specify the time zone, then you would need to include the time zone in the format/`String` value.  If you can't change the original value, you could append the time zone value to the end of the `String` before you parse it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your problem either but here is my best effort to answer it for you.

I assume you have a date as a string which is in UTC timezone and you want the date as the systems (or your local) timezone.

To do this simply add the String `" UTC"` to your time string and change your date formatter pattern to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z". Here `Z` is [RFC 822 time zone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone). You could also use `z` which is [General time zone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone).

So your code would become:

```
String timezoneOffset = " UTC";
dateFormatterLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");  
dateFormatterLocal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New York"));
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
   timeStampArrayList.add(dateFormatterLocal.parse(list[i] + timezoneOffset ));
}
```

This should then parse the date to the time zone of the formatter converted from the time zone string provided.

---

You can do this to get the Systems current timezone

```
TimeZone timeZone = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone();
System.out.println(timeZone.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.LONG));
```

Which prints `New Zealand Standard Time` for me - which is the current timezone.

You can also change `TimeZone.LONG` to `TimeZone.SHORT` to get the abbreviated version i.e. I get `NZST`

---

Also you should read [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207110/parsing-formatted-date-string-in-another-timezone-to-date-object-not-working) about displaying Date