# Get Date in UTC using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to use SimpleDateFormat to parse a Date and Time string in scala. I want the Date object which is created to be in UTC format but it converts it into my Local Timezone. Setting Timezone or calendar is not working.

```
scala> new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
scala> res41.parse("2014-12-12 13:12:45")
//java.util.Date = Fri Dec 12 13:12:45 IST 2014
```

After setting Timezone like `res41.setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))` (res41 is the instance of SimpleDateFormat in Scala REPL) gives me the same result.

If I set `Calendar`, like `res41.setCalendar(cal)` where `cal` is an instance of `java.util.Calendar` with Timezone as UTC also, does not change the result.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207110/parsing-formatted-date-string-in-another-timezone-to-date-object-not-working (Though since then the Java8 improvements might provide better answers.)

Comment: @GáborBakos - Your mentioned question seems to handle only date objects. It does not answer my question.

Comment: You can manually add the UTC time zone to the String to parse and the format. That way, the `Date` will be in the UTC time zone. I am not sure why would you need the `Calendar`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Let me try. However, I will get 10000s of strings. I don't want to iterate twice to get collection of Timestamps.

Comment: Tried the following code in java. It seems to work fine.DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
  System.out.println(sdf.parse("2014-12-12 13:12:45")); result: Fri Dec 12 18:42:45 IST 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## java.time

You can use the [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into [Java 8](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history). It is much easier to use than java.util classes.

```
import java.time.ZoneId
java.time.LocalDateTime.now()
java.time.LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("GMT"))
java.time.LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"))
java.time.LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Australia/Sydney"))
```

Using [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html), it is possible to get the time for different time zones. Use proper [time zone names](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

## Joda-Time

You could also use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), especially if you are not using Java 8. See  [`DateTimeZone`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html).